# JSF ajax behaviour listener

Tags: events, jsf-2

I've a problem when I use selectOneRadio and the renderer of my panels.

My cession.xhtml contains this

```
    <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{editionBean.radioProprietaire}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Particulier" itemValue="particulier" />
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Societe" itemValue="societe" />
      <f:ajax listener="#{editionBean.listener}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.renderSoc}">...</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.renderPart}">...</h:panelGroup>
```

My EditionBean.class

```
private boolean renderSoc;
private boolean renderPart;
private String radioProprietaire;

public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
  if(null != radioProprietaire && radioProprietaire.equals("particulier")){
           renderPart = true;
       renderSoc = false;
      }
  else if(null != radioProprietaire && radioProprietaire.equals("societe")){
    renderPart = false;
    renderSoc = true;
      }
  }
```

I know that method listener is call, but ths panels aren't visible, if someone can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. You need `<p:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>` in PrimeFaces components.
2. You need to explicitly specify a JSF component in the ajax update so that it will be re-rendered. With the current approach, you're basically updating nothing. With `<f:ajax>`, the to-be-updated components should be specified in `render` attribute and with `<p:ajax>` in `update` attribute.

Further, there's some inefficiency going on. You don't need the listener method and those lot of boolean properties at all. You can just check the radio button value directly in the `rendered` attribute.

So, all with all, this should do:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{editionBean.radioProprietaire}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Particulier" itemValue="particulier" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Societe" itemValue="societe" />
    <p:ajax update="groups" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGroup id="groups">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.radioProprietaire == 'societe'}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.radioProprietaire == 'particulier'}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/)

Comment: Can I change my file editionBean ? or web.xml or another config file ?

Comment: You have only to remove unused properties and unused listener method.

Comment: Yes my bean contains only attributs and its getters and setters only (I can't post my code because i need 10 in reputations ^^)

Comment: Here, you can see my code 
http://hubertpicardat.fr/sites/edition.xhtml.txt
http://hubertpicardat.fr/sites/edition.java.txt

Comment: What are all those `<h:column>` doing there in your view? Remove them. Further, please descibe your concrete problem clearly. The above answer should solve your problem, but you have never explicitly confirmed nor denied the solution.

Comment: Ohh thank a lot @BalusC, when I delete my <h:column>, my panels appear. Thank you !!!! you're the best ! thanks you Luiggi too !! 
StackOverFlow is wonderfull

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415040/1065197), you should wrap the `<h:panelGroup>` component inside an `UIContainer` and render that bigger container in order to make the panel to *become visible*:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{editionBean.radioProprietaire}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Particulier" itemValue="particulier" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Societe" itemValue="societe" />
  <p:ajax listener="#{editionBean.listener}" render="pnlSoc pnlPart" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid id="pnlSoc">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.renderSoc}">...</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid id="pnlPart">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editionBean.renderPart}">...</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but when I'm clicking on the radioButton, nothing appear...

Comment: Are the components (the select radioand the panel groups) in the same `<h:form>`?

Comment: Yes its are in the same h:form

Comment: Note that the comma in `<f:ajax render>` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @BalusC fixed it, sometimes I get confused with RichFaces `reRender` syntax.

Comment: I'm fixing it on my code, i don't understand where is the problem and I'm learning JSF since 1 week and I search a solution on this problem since 2 days. Thanks a lot Luiggi ;)

Comment: @user1992926 you're welcome, but use BalusC answer instead, he's a JSF 2 expert.

Comment: Anyone have a issue for me ?

Comment: @user1992926 what do you mean?

Comment: the panelGroup doesn't appear when I select a RadioButton.

Comment: @user1992926 have you tried [BalusC answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14415454/1065197)?

Comment: @user1992926 clean and rebuild the project, redeploy it in your web application server and try again. If you have any errors using BalusC's approach then ask him commenting his answer, not mine.